# Django self referencing model filter ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

say i have following model in Django:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Is there a way to prevent referencing to same category? Right django generates select field in admin area where im able to select same category as parent. Is there some way to filter that select in admin?

Comment: did you find a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ForeignKey.limit_choices_to` - see [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit%5fchoices%5fto)

You haven't provided enough of a code snippet to see how that would be done in your case, but I'm guessing on the `parent` ForeignKey, you'd want to limit the choices to a lambda function that checks to see if the name of the category is the same as the one doing the referencing.

You probably want a lambda function here, not a single expression.